# Load all images from contentProvider on Android 10

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentprovider, android-10.0

I am currently using the following code to load all images from the Android `contentProvider` in my repository:

```
    override suspend fun getLocalImagePaths() = SuspendableResult.of<List<String>, Exception> {
        val result = mutableListOf<String>()
        val uri: Uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)
        contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null)?.use {
            val dataIndex = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)
            while (it.moveToNext()) {
                result.add(it.getString(dataIndex))
            }
        }
        result
    }
```

This gets the absolute paths to all available images and it seems to work in Android 9, allthough some images can't be loaded (I am using Glide), but in Android 10 I can't load any of the image paths that are returned from the mentioned method. How could I do this?

Comment: Query for the `ID` values. Then, use `ContentUris.withAppendedId()` to get a `Uri` for the individual image. Return a `List<Uri>`, and hand the `Uri` values over to Glide.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you give me an example? Am I only doing this on Android 10 or on all API levels?

Comment: [Here](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/blob/v0.5/ConferenceVideos/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/conferencevideos/VideoRepository.kt) I am querying for videos matching a particular display name, but the concept is the same. "Am I only doing this on Android 10 or on all API levels?" -- preferably, all API levels. There is no requirement for `DATA` to have a useful value.

Comment: This works now (see the resolution answer). Can you shortly explain what the `ContentUris.withAppendedId` does?

Comment: It builds a `Uri` from a base `Uri` and an ID of a particular piece of content. `MediaStore` follows that pattern, so you can get a `Uri` for an image given its ID. And `MediaStore` is set to make the actual content available from the `Uri`. Glide knows how to use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to read in the image given the `Uri`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    override suspend fun getLocalImagePaths() = SuspendableResult.of<List<Uri>, Exception> {
        val result = mutableListOf<Uri>()
        val uri: Uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
        contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null)?.use {
            while (it.moveToNext()) {
                result.add(
                    ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        it.getLong(0)
                    )
                )
            }
        }
        result
    }
```